# Why does the variable defined in the included script have no value?

Tags: php, session, variables

I have this code in script.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$user_session = $_SESSION['u_name'];

class check_sess {
    public function check_id_session($user_session, $db) { //email
        $stmt = $db->prepare('select id_user from users where email=?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user_session);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id);

        if ($stmt -> fetch()) {
            $id;
            echo $id; // here shows 20 for example
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;

        $stmt->close();
        $db->close();
    }
}
?>
```

and in demo.php I have:

```
include 'script.php';
$val = new check_sess();
$val-> check_id_session($user_session, $db);
echo $id; //problem here. It is supposed echo 20
```

Why can't I do `echo $id`? There is no output in demo.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope). The variable `$id` does not exist outside the function. If you want the function to return $id, write `return $id` in the `if ($stmt -> fetch()) {` condition branch. You can then write:

```
include 'script.php';
$val = new check_sess();
$id = $val-> check_id_session($user_session, $db);
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value to access it in this way:

```
if ($stmt -> fetch()) {
     return $id; 
}
```

Except that won't work as you intended.

You need to assign `$id` first - and it looks like you're using some kind of framework; so you should first assign the value to `$id`, as a result from say, `fetch()`, and then return that value from the method, allowing you to access it.

Answer (score 1):

your id is within a class and therefore in a different scope.

You can either write a getter for it or declare it as static, then you can access it without an instance:

```
class check_sess {
    static $id;
...
    if ($stmt -> fetch()) {
        self::$id = $id;
        echo self::$id; // here shows 20 for example
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

You can now access it anywhere in your code via

```
check_sess::$id
```